# Please tag-synonym all of the [code-reuse] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Stack Overflow has 6 unsynonymed tags related to reusable code:

[code-reuse](/questions/tagged/code-reuse)
[reuse](/questions/tagged/reuse)
[reusable-code](/questions/tagged/reusable-code)
[reusability](/questions/tagged/reusability)
[reusable](/questions/tagged/reusable)
[reusing-code](/questions/tagged/reusing-code)

Could a moderator please make them all be one synonym, probably under the [code-reuse](/questions/tagged/code-reuse) master because it already has a wiki.

Comment: The more interesting question is: Do we need any of those?

Comment: @animuson: aha, it's [meta-tag:synonym-request], not [meta-tag:tag-synonyms]. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be willing to group them into the following:

- [reusing-code](/questions/tagged/reusing-code) and [reusable-code](/questions/tagged/reusable-code) into [code-reuse](/questions/tagged/code-reuse)
- [reuse](/questions/tagged/reuse) and [reusable](/questions/tagged/reusable) into [reusablity](/questions/tagged/reusablity)

Not sure about merging the two groups together.  I think it requires more research to do that, but I don't see any problems with the first level of groupings.

---

Here's the end result:

- [reusing-code](/questions/tagged/reusing-code) didn't have any questions in it when I got to it, so I don't see the need to create a synonym here.
- [reusable-code](/questions/tagged/reusable-code) was merged into [code-reuse](/questions/tagged/code-reuse)
- [reusable](/questions/tagged/reusable) only had 38 questions associated with it, so I retagged them manually to [reuse](/questions/tagged/reuse)
- [reuse](/questions/tagged/reuse) was merged into [reusability](/questions/tagged/reusability)

That said, [I agree with Ral Zarek that we should ask if we need these tags at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157590/please-tag-synonym-all-of-the-code-reuse-tags/157592#comment455104_157590), and that the questions in them should be reviewed and the tags possibly removed.

Comment: @durron597 Doing that now.

Comment: @durron597 Chill, homie.  We got day jobs too!

Comment: @durron597 Done.

Comment: @durron597 I'll retag those.  Don't know why they didn't come up before.

Comment: @durron597 That's done.  See updated answer.